# transaction pending but now showing on MEW

Tags: transactions

I wanted to transfer ERC20 tokens to transfer from metamask to exchange. However I accidentally set 2 gwei, which was very low. Now my transaction is pending and it doesn't showing up in myetherwallet as a pending status. Can this transaction be automatically cancelled or I have to do something? (transaction is not showing up, so I am not able to replace or cancel it)

**TRANSACTION SHOWING HERE** https://etherscan.io/address/0x3cef0911c527cfd6bdc8cf9045f38c2da29787dd

**SAME TRANSACTION NOT SHOWING HERE (using TXHASH on MEW)** 
Go to: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#check-tx-status

**& paste TxHash:** 0x113d0136b7286ca8cc1fdd03d82c9e52e9e23e8bb88eecc081d2e45a57e46ac1

**MY QUESTION**
this transaction will ever be executed or not? What should I do to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that transaction confirmed, you can retry with a higher gas price. You may see the message on your MetaMask, `Taking too long? Retry with a higher gas price here`. With retrying, you will send the same transaction (with the same nonce) with different gas price.

In other words, as I can see your transaction's nonce is 17, you can send the transaction in the MEW with nonce 17. Then, it will replace your previous transaction.